# Will it harm the transmission to drive with a defective Turbine Speed Sensor?

Tags: automatic-transmission, mazda-626

I recently got a 0715 DTC ( 98 Mazda 626 GF 2L, GF4A-EL transmission ) which is related to the [turbine speed sensor](http://www.autozone.com/repairinfo/repairguide/repairGuideContent.jsp?pageId=0996b43f81b3cb11).  Some of the symptoms according to the ATSG transmission manual are harsh and erratic shifting, which I've been experiencing since the code was thrown.  In the manual it says that in case of a malfunction in this sensor shifts are made based on the speedometer.

Is it safe for the transmission to drive it like this?  I've only driven a little since getting the code and have tried to drive very conservatively.